# Angularjs - cloned html is losing $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an AngularJS wit a <nav> element that is used for desktops:

```
<nav ng-controller="MainNavController" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
```

The problem is that for mobile, I need to implement an off-canvas navigation where the whole body is shifted over and the nav appears to slide in from the right.

To do this, instead of duplicating the entire nav on the page in the initial html payload, I thought I'd do this by using jQuery.clone().

However, when I do this, I'm losing the $scope context.  The ng-click functions in my copied-over anchors are not being fired.

I'm copying these items over in a directive and I tried calling scope.$apply() but it didn't work.

```
$(".prenav > *").clone().appendTo($(".off-canvas__nav"));
scope.$apply();
```

It seems from my reading on this that I need to somehow call a $compile on this new html, but I'm not sure how/when to do this in my current setup.

Any help would be appreciated.

-- Scott

Answer (score 0):

You need to [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) it first, otherwise Angular sees it just as a pile of wood:

```
scope.$apply(function(){
  var newNav = $(".prenav > *").clone();
  $compile(newNav)(scope);
  newNav.appendTo($(".off-canvas__nav"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm now getting a [ngTransclude:orphan] error.  Any ideas?

Comment: You're welcome. Try one of the fixes from here: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngTransclude/orphan

Comment: Hmm.. there is a lot of stuff going on in the nav that I'm copying.  I probably need to get the original markup and clone that, instead of the post-compiled markup. I have some angular-ui-select dropdowns and angular-ui-boostrap collapses, etc....

Comment: Yes, definitely. In fact, why don't you simply have both versions and use `ng-if` to denote which one gets loaded. That way you'd avoid all that jQuery-like functionality (which is always good). Without seeing more of the code, I'm afraid I can't give you anything more accurate.

Comment: Ooo, that's an idea.  Thanks.